# Is there a way to restrict public key to only one/IP

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat

I have a web application server running with SSL certificate validation. 
The private and public keys generated using java keygen tool.

Now is there a way that I can restrict the public key to only one IP address?
I tried to google the solution but a lot of forums suggest to either use `IPSec` or `.htaccess` or edit the `server.xml`

I am not on Windows so cant use IPSec, I cannot  edit the .htaccess as there are other applications running on the same server so they all will inherit the IP block. I am not inclined towards editing the server.xml and would like to find another solution like `restricting public key to one IP`

I am also open to any other solutions.

I would really appreciate any help on this as I am currently blocked because of this requirement.

P.S. I am deploying my application on Tomcat server.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I need to make sure that only a request from certain IP address can call my service hence the IP block and also need the data exchange to be encrypted hence the SSL certificates.

Comment: Then you should use firewall to configure IP/port restrictions.

Comment: You don't need Windows to use IPSec either.

Comment: @HBruijn Aah, I read it at one of the forums while Googling. Wrong/half info is dangerous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an [remote address filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter) in your applications `web.xml` to restrict access to certain (ranges of) ip-addresses.

To allow only localhost:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```